# Recommendations for murder mystery party

Tags: game-recommendation, larp, investigation

I want to run a murder mystery party. Basically, a party where, in addition to all the drinking and dancing, there's also a murder investigation LARP going on.

At first, I was thinking of designing the game myself, but surely there's already something out there for the needs of people like me.

**What systems, books, sets or something pre-made would you recommend?** Preferably stuff you tried yourself.

Comment: As this is a [tag:system-recommendation] question, please adhere to both the [FAQ] and the rules for subjective questions as outlined in [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) and on [our Meta](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/1071/760).  In particular, all responses should be based on actual experience and contain references and examples whenever possible.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of these available. See: [Murder Mystery Game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murder_mystery_game). In the UK I have seen lots of these in charity shops for next to nothing unused. There was a time a few years back when they where Christmas presents which a lot of people never even opened them.

See here for some [Examples](http://www.dmoz.org/Games/Party_Games/Murder_Mystery/).

Answer (score 1):

We decided to try a murder mystery for Halloween. I can recommend it because we had great success with it. The kit we purchased is called [Four Dueces](http://www.dinnerandamurder.com/games/4deuces.htm). Dinner and casino games are a great way to warm people up to their characters.

We also wanted to create our own Lovecraftian/Occult murder mystery event, but decided to use a kit this year since it was easier. Maybe next time. At least now we have a better idea what to expect from our group of friends.